# Setting AWS CLI Profile to issue bash commands against AWS

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am trying to setup the AWS env variables for AWS profiles before I run a bash script.

If do:

```
export profile=$(AWS_PROFILE=name)
aws configure list
```

and then I `echo $profile` it isn't setting the profile.

Comment: Not quite sure what your question is, but if it's how do I run `aws configure list` for a given profile then 1) `AWS_PROFILE=rodney aws configure list` or 2) `aws configure list --profile rodney`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
export AWS_PROFILE=rodney
<call script here>
```

Alternatively, in the script you can specify a profile:

```
aws s3 ls --profile rodney
```

Comment: Thanks! I was overcomplicating things